# Integral inequality with sin exp

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, summation

For $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}\sin (\text{e}^t)\text{d}t$

Prove that :
$\displaystyle \text{e}^x\left|f(x)\right|\le 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}\sin (\text{e}^t)\text{d}t\implies \displaystyle e^xf(x)=\int_x^{x+1}e^x\sin (\text{e}^t)\text{d}t \leq \int_x^{x+1}e^t\sin (\text{e}^t)\text{d}t $   (because $x\leq t\leq x+1)$

Now substitute $z=e^t$ which gives

$\displaystyle e^xf(x)\leq\int_{e^x}^{e^{x+1}}\sin (\text{z})\text{d}z=\cos(e^{x})-\cos(e^{x+1})\implies e^x|f(x)|\leq |\cos(e^{x})|+|\cos(e^{x+1})|\leq 2$

Comment: I can't understand last inequality
$$\int_{e^x}^{e^{x+1}}|\sin z |dz\le |\cos e^x|+|\cos e^{x+1}|.$$
I think if $x$ is arbitary large, this inequalty fails.

Comment: @tetori: i am done with editing, have a look

Comment: Seems to be correct.

Comment: Thx, but can we put e^x straight into integral sign for the first line?

Comment: For that integral , $x$ is just a fixed value as it is appearing in the limits , so there is no problem in just taking the $e^x$ inside the integral

Comment: @Avatar: OK, I see... thank you :)